# Cannot autowire a view class because a problem with a argument InterfaceType

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on a clean architecture project, in this project I am trying to show a search bar on my main page and include an API, to add my search bar I use a form bundle of Symfony, so in my "Domain" repo I have: "Entity"; "Form"; "Presenter"; "Request"; "Response"; and "UseCase" repositories;

In my "Form"  repository, I have my search bar class:

```
namespace Domain\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;

class SearchFormType implements AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add("car", TextType::class, [
                "label" => "Rechercher une voiture",
                "required" => true,
                "attr" => [
                    "placeholder" => "Rechercher"
                ]
            ]);
    }
}
```

In my UseCase I have a function that must include the Api with form information, this class is not finished, but this i not the problem:

UseCase:

```
namespace Domain\UseCase;

use Domain\Request\SearchCarRequest;
use Infrastructure\dataProviders\carsSearchApi;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;

class SearchCarUseCase
{

    private $model;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function searchCar(FormInterface $form, string $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
        $carApi = new carsSearchApi($model);
    }

    public function validateModel(SearchCarRequest $request)
    {
        $request->model = $this->model;
    }
}
```

I Forgot controller class who call viewpage class and UseCase:

```
namespace Infrastructure\Symfony\controller;

use Domain\Form\SearchFormType;
use Domain\Presenter\SearchCarPresenterInterface;
use Domain\UseCase\SearchCarUseCase;
use Infrastructure\Symfony\view\SearchHtmlView;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Twig\Error\LoaderError;
use Twig\Error\RuntimeError;
use Twig\Error\SyntaxError;

#[Route("/", name: "main")]
class mainController extends AbstractController
{

    public string $model;
    private SearchHtmlView $searchView;
    private SearchCarUseCase $carUseCase;
    private SearchCarPresenterInterface $presenter;

    public function __construct(
        SearchHtmlView $searchView,
        SearchCarUseCase $carUseCase,
        SearchCarPresenterInterface $presenter
    )
    {
        $this->searchView = $searchView;
        $this->carUseCase = $carUseCase;
        $this->presenter = $presenter;
    }

    /**
     * @throws SyntaxError
     * @throws RuntimeError
     * @throws LoaderError
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $carRequest): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(SearchFormType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($carRequest);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->model = $form->get("car")->getData();

            $this->carUseCase->searchCar($form, $this->model);
        }
        $this->addFlash("message", "veuillez remplir le champ demande");

        return $this->searchView->generateView($form);
    }

}
```

This class is not located in the Domain folder but Infrastructure > Symfony > Controllers.

And at last I have SearchHtmlView.php class, this class retrieves all the information and generates the view, and there is the problem:

```
namespace Infrastructure\Symfony\view;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Twig\Environment;
use Twig\Error\LoaderError;
use Twig\Error\RuntimeError;
use Twig\Error\SyntaxError;


class SearchHtmlView
{

    private Environment $twig;
    private FormInterface $form;

    public function __construct(Environment $twig, FormInterface $form)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
        $this->form = $form;
    }

    /**
     * @throws RuntimeError
     * @throws SyntaxError
     * @throws LoaderError
     */
    public function generateView(FormInterface $form): Response
    {
        return new Response($this->twig->render(
            'main/main.html.twig',
            [
                "form" => $this->form->createView()
            ]
        ));
    }
}
```

PS: I know my UseCase class is not finished and implementation of API not finished to, but the problem is not here.

So this is what my page show:

#### Cannot autowire service "Infrastructure\Symfony\view\SearchHtmlView": argument "$form" of method "__construct()" references interface "Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface" but no such service exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?

I try to do that in my formType class :

```
namespace Domain\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;

abstract class SearchFormType implements FormInterface
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add("car", TextType::class, [
                "label" => "Rechercher une voiture",
                "required" => true,
                "attr" => [
                    "placeholder" => "Rechercher"
                ]
            ]);
    }
}
```

change it to an abstract class and implement FormInterface. but that doesn't work, it's my first project in clean architecture and I do not understand everything.

Comment: I know there must be other errors in the code, I would like to fix this one first and fix the rest in the future, if you need anything please don't hesitate

Comment: Why do you need to inject any form ito that class and not use that? `$form` should be enough

Comment: yes, it makes so much sense. But now the problem is that I have this error in other classes and always in relation to the __construct. And in these classes I inject what I need via the constructor and I cannot do otherwise. The error is the same

Comment: By understanding how to fix this I could get rid of this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject in a `Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory`, and use it like this!

```
$form = $this->formFactory->create(
    YourType::class,
    $data,
    $options
);
```

Comment: I inject it directly into my view class? but won't this pose a problem when I have to retrieve what is entered in the form to return a result via the API?

Comment: Don't put it in your view, put it in your controller or service class :-)